# Calling convention for function returning struct

Tags: c, windows, linux, x86, calling-convention

For the following C code:

```
struct _AStruct {
    int a;
    int b;
    float c;
    float d;
    int e;
};

typedef struct _AStruct AStruct;

AStruct test_callee5();
void test_caller5();

void test_caller5() {
    AStruct g = test_callee5();
    AStruct h = test_callee5();    
}
```

I get the following disassembly for Win32:

```
_test_caller5:
  00000000: lea         eax,[esp-14h]
  00000004: sub         esp,14h
  00000007: push        eax
  00000008: call        _test_callee5
  0000000D: lea         ecx,[esp+4]
  00000011: push        ecx
  00000012: call        _test_callee5
  00000017: add         esp,1Ch
  0000001A: ret
```

And for Linux32:

```
00000000 <test_caller5>:
   0:  push   %ebp
   1:  mov    %esp,%ebp
   3:  sub    $0x38,%esp
   6:  lea    0xffffffec(%ebp),%eax
   9:  mov    %eax,(%esp)
   c:  call   d <test_caller5+0xd>
  11:  sub    $0x4,%esp  ;;;;;;;;;; Note this extra sub ;;;;;;;;;;;;
  14:  lea    0xffffffd8(%ebp),%eax
  17:  mov    %eax,(%esp)
  1a:  call   1b <test_caller5+0x1b>
  1f:  sub    $0x4,%esp   ;;;;;;;;;; Note this extra sub ;;;;;;;;;;;;
  22:  leave
  23:  ret
```

I am trying to understand the difference in how the caller behaves after the call. 
Why does the caller in Linux32 do these extra subs?

I would assume that both targets would follow the cdecl calling convention. Doesn't cdecl define the calling convention for a function returning a structure?!

EDIT:

I added an implementation of the callee. And sure enough, you can see that the Linux32 callee pops its argument, while the Win32 callee does not:

```
AStruct test_callee5()
{
    AStruct S={0};
    return S;
}
```

Win32 disassembly:

```
test_callee5:
  00000000: mov         eax,dword ptr [esp+4]
  00000004: xor         ecx,ecx
  00000006: mov         dword ptr [eax],0
  0000000C: mov         dword ptr [eax+4],ecx
  0000000F: mov         dword ptr [eax+8],ecx
  00000012: mov         dword ptr [eax+0Ch],ecx
  00000015: mov         dword ptr [eax+10h],ecx
  00000018: ret
```

Linux32 disassembly:

```
00000000 <test_callee5>:
   0:   push   %ebp
   1:   mov    %esp,%ebp
   3:   sub    $0x20,%esp
   6:   mov    0x8(%ebp),%edx
   9:   movl   $0x0,0xffffffec(%ebp)
  10:   movl   $0x0,0xfffffff0(%ebp)
  17:   movl   $0x0,0xfffffff4(%ebp)
  1e:   movl   $0x0,0xfffffff8(%ebp)
  25:   movl   $0x0,0xfffffffc(%ebp)
  2c:   mov    0xffffffec(%ebp),%eax
  2f:   mov    %eax,(%edx)
  31:   mov    0xfffffff0(%ebp),%eax
  34:   mov    %eax,0x4(%edx)
  37:   mov    0xfffffff4(%ebp),%eax
  3a:   mov    %eax,0x8(%edx)
  3d:   mov    0xfffffff8(%ebp),%eax
  40:   mov    %eax,0xc(%edx)
  43:   mov    0xfffffffc(%ebp),%eax
  46:   mov    %eax,0x10(%edx)
  49:   mov    %edx,%eax
  4b:   leave
  4c:   ret    $0x4  ;;;;;;;;;;;;;; Note this ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

Comment: do not start identifiers with underscores: such names are reserved for compiler+libc implementation; starting identifiers with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter is even worse, as that's what new language keywords use (eg `_Bool`, `_Complex` from C99 and `_Alignas`, `_Generic` from C1x)

Comment: Could you also disassemble the function itself? You will likely find the function in Windows with extra instructions then. As mentioned, there is no standard for this. "cdecl", "stdcall" etc etc are not part of the C/C++ standards.

Comment: This is an interesting question. It does not look like it was ever really answered though. I'm still looking into it.

Comment: Related: [How C structures get passed to function in assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57766693) is mostly x86-64 Windows and Linux pass and return, while this is 32-bit struct returns.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Why does the caller in Linux32 do these extra subs?

The reason is the use of a hidden pointer ([named return value optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization)), injected by the compiler, for returning the struct by value. In SystemV's [ABI](http://www.sco.com/developers/devspecs/abi386-4.pdf), page 41, in the section about "Function Returning Structures or Unions", it says:

> *The called function must remove this address from the stack before returning.*

That is why you get a `ret $0x4` at the end of `test_callee5()`, it is for compliance with the ABI.

Now about the presence of `sub $0x4, %esp` just after each `test_callee5()` call sites, it is a side-effect of the above rule, combined with optimized code generated by the C compiler. As the local storage stack space is pre-reserved entirely by:

```
3:  sub    $0x38,%esp
```

there is no need to push/pop the hidden pointer, it is just written at bottom of the pre-reserved space (pointed at by `esp`), using `mov %eax,(%esp)` at lines 9 and 17. As the stack pointer is not decremented, the `sub $0x4,%esp` is there to negate the effect of `ret $0x4`, and keep the stack pointer unchanged.

On Win32 (using MSVC compiler I guess), there is no such ABI rule, a simple `ret` is used (as expected in cdecl), the hidden pointer is pushed on the stack at line 7 and 11. Though, those slots are not freed after the calls, as an optimization, but only before callee exits, using an `add esp,1Ch`, freeing the hidden pointer stack slots (2 * 0x4 bytes) and the local `AStruct`struct (0x14 bytes).

> Doesn't cdecl define the calling convention for a function returning a structure?!

Unfortunately, it does not, it varies with C compilers and operating systems

Comment: On a side note: Using `sub  $0x38,%esp` & making space for the hidden pointer up front also has the advantage that the compiler can more easily maintain 16-byte stack alignment (in this case) at the point of function calls. This is part of the later [i386 Linux ABI](https://www.uclibc.org/docs/psABI-i386.pdf)  which says _The end of the input argument area shall be aligned on a 16 (32, if __m256 is passed on stack) byte boundary_.  After control is transferred to `test_callee5` stack is misaligned by 4. The push EBP misaligns its by 8. 0x08+0x38=0x40. 0x40 is evenly divisible by 16 once again.

Comment: Very interesting insight, and thank you for providing a link to a much more recent Linux ABI document!

Answer (score 1):

There is no single "cdecl" calling convention. It is defined by the compiler and operating system.

Also reading the assembly I am not actually sure the convention is actually different—in both cases the caller is providing buffer for the output as extra argument. It's just that gcc chose different instructions (the second extra sub is strange; is that code optimized?).