# EOF value in float type

Tags: c, eof

In Kernighan and Ritchie's C book, Im asked to write a program to print the value of EOF

I did it right by writing:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
void main(){
    printf("%d", EOF);
}
```

I got it right by getting -1 as the answer...but out of curiosity I typed `%f` instead of `%d`. It's displaying 0.00000000

Why is that?

I got what I expected...but the latter (printing in float type), I did it out of curiosity, and thought the result should be -1.0 or something like that.

Comment: Mismatching format specifier and argument type leads to *undefined behavior*. The `%f` format expects a `double` value, while `EOF` is an `int` value.

Comment: to print if as float you need to explicitly convert it to float `printf("%f", (double)EOF);`

Comment: negative `1` interpreted as a int is NaN, interesting that it prints `0` instead of `nan` like you would expect

Comment: For different application binary interfaces (ABIs), parameters may be passed on the stack and/or in registers. And the registers used may depend on the type of the parameter. For example, floating point parameters may be passed in different registers to integer or pointer parameters.

Comment: @mousetail Because `%f` expects a `double` which is usually 64 bits, while `int` is typically 32 bits. Which means that there's 32 bits or garbage data being passed. Also the actual result will depend on the endianness of the system.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57859857/what-is-the-calling-convention-for-floating-point-values-in-c-for-x86-64-in-syst to get an explanation for what the program may do (But it is still UB, so don't relay on it).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude AMD64, which the OP most likely uses, uses different registers for floating point parameters than integers.

Comment: OT: Return type of `main()` should be `int` not `void`. Enable compiler warnings (probably `-Wall -Wextra`).

Comment: All arguments of calls to `printf` except the first argument containing the format string are *variadlc* arguments and will be passed using the *default argument promotion rules*. (`printf` is declared `int printf(const char *restrict format, ...);`. The `, ...` is a placeholder for zero or more *variadic* arguments.) `printf` uses the format string to decide how may variadic arguments it is expecting and their types. If the actual number of variadic arguments or their types are not as expected, that will result in *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, you can test it with `printf("%f\n", 1, 1234.5678);`.

Answer (score 1):

If the parameter of the `printf` does not match the format you invoke the Undefined Behaviour (UB).

You need to convert it to the double before passing to the `printf` function:

```
printf("%f", (double)EOF);
```