Returning a double from asm to c
I am looking to take two double variables, pass them to a function, subtract them, return them and print the result.
My example:
#include <stdio.h>
extern double dev(double a, double b);
int main() {
    double a = 10.2;
    double b = 3.6;
    double result = dev(a, b);
    printf("%.2f", result);
    return 0;
}

Asm:
section .text
    global dev
dev:
    movsd xmm0, [rdi]
    movsd xmm1, [rsi]
    subsd xmm0, xmm1
    ret

It compiles, however when I attempt to run the code I get a Segmentation fault (core dumped)
I believe I have identified the problem, I just am not sure how to fix it.
double is a 64 bit value. Whereas xmm is a 128 bit register. It would seem logical (at least to me) I am attempting to return 128 bits, however I see no way of doing it. I tried movsd rax xmm0 but same issue

Did you try to just define a C function with same parameters and return type and see how the compiler accesses them?

What operating system are you programming for?

You didn't pass the parameters by address, but your function assumes the parameters are pointers. Floating point values are passed and returned in xmm registers on x86-64.

@fuz Linux mint

Recommend read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57859857/what-is-the-calling-convention-for-floating-point-values-in-c-for-x86-64-in-syst

@chtz: I added a simple TL:DR and example to the top of the answer to that question, making it a good duplicate target for questions like this.

In this case, one approach is to look at how the compiler implements a similar function: https://godbolt.org/z/zv8cY3GfG (no optimization) or https://godbolt.org/z/zn8ecKT1f (optimization level "O2").
The first one gives the following (making it apparent that the parameters are passed in registers xmm0 and xmm1):
dev:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        movsd   QWORD PTR [rbp-8], xmm0
        movsd   QWORD PTR [rbp-16], xmm1
        movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        subsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR [rbp-16]
        pop     rbp
        ret

The optimized version is as follows:
dev:
        subsd   xmm0, xmm1
        ret

Which illustrates one reason why it perhaps is increasingly uncommon to see embedded assembly: compilers are getting increasingly good at creating optimized assembler code and assembler code is getting more and more optimized towards compilers making it difficult for humans to create good assembler code. The effort and restriction to a specific target CPU is seldomly worth it.

Nothing about this is difficult for humans, OP just didn't know how the double parameters are passed in the calling convention he was working in

@user555045 I was talking more generally, I assume this is a minimal example.

@user555045 I am admittedly very new to assembly. I'm familiar with a lot of the processes that happen with memory registers, but even apparently simple debugging steps like this are unknown to me :D

I don't honestly consider assembly a reasonable way to achieve most tasks, however I am interested to deepen my understanding how processes actually work under the hood. Thank you :)

The dev function you provided currently is trying to load a and b from rdi and rsi. Since these are not valid memory addresses for double values, attempting to load double values from them causes a segmentation fault.
Probably need to adjust your dev function that uses the correct registers for double arguments.
section .text
    global dev
dev:
    subsd xmm0, xmm1
    ret


Optimized (assuming returing b-a)
dev:
        subsd   xmm1, xmm0
        movaps  xmm0, xmm1
        ret

Not optimized
dev:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        movsd   QWORD PTR [rbp-8], xmm0
        movsd   QWORD PTR [rbp-16], xmm1
        movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR [rbp-16]
        subsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        pop     rbp
        ret


The OP's code does return *a - *b.  But yes they're passed by value in XMM regs, not as double * args in integer regs.

@PeterCordes if cant do *a or *b as function protoptype is  extern double dev(double a, double b);

The asm they wrote doesn't match that prototype, it's expecting pointers or C++ references.  My point is that it's a - b or *a - *b since RDI is the first pointer arg, RSI is the second.

Implementation is wrong and thats the problem.

Yes, obviously.  But your assumption of return b-a also doesn't match what they wanted to do.
